# What is the relationship between /usr/lib/golang/src and /usr/lib/golang/pkg

Tags: go

If I install the distro packages for Go, I see a lot of files in `/usr/lib/golang/pkg` and a very similar set of files in `/usr/lib/golang/src`.  What is the relationship between these two sets?

Is `pkg` a compiled library produced from the source code in `src`?

Assuming a Go program using standard packages like `fmt`, is the compiled library in `pkg` needed to run Go programs?  Is it needed to compile Go programs?  Is the source in `src` needed to compile Go programs?

Comment: "Is the source in src needed to compile Go programs?" Yes, of course. Otherwise you would have to provide precompiled versions of the whole stdlib for _all_ architectures and _all_ OS; with the sources you can just crosscompile.

Comment: What if you are using one of the architecture and OS combinations that does exist as a precompiled library, which I take it is what is in /usr/lib/golang/pkg?  Would the source still be necessary?

Comment: 1. You should install Go from the official source and not from your distro. 2. Source from the stdlib are in src, compiled packages in pkg. 3. If a package is not available in pkg it will be compiled from src. 4. If a package is available it won't be compiled from source. 5. There is nothing wrong with having the source installed, it makes e.g. debugging and displaying documentation much simpler. 6. This is a non-problem as the go tool handles all this transparently. 7. Once more: Use the official version.

Comment: There is no official go for my custom embedded Linux device with an SDK built using yocto.  This does not include the src part of the go stdlib.  I'm trying to determine if this is actually necessary or not.  Fedora puts golang into src and bin packages, but is not clear if src is required just to compile software if the appropriate bin package is also available.   Most if not virtually all compiled languages do NOT require full source the standard library to compile any software.  Maybe go does?

Comment: Well, what's wrong with trying it out and deleting the src folder. Why are you now talking about the bin folder? I'm not familiar with yocto but as Go doesn't need much (nothing if using netgo) it simply should not matter. Are you cross compiling? What are your actual trying to do? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Fedora names the packages golang-src and golang-bin.  The latter has the compiled libraries in `/usr/lib/golang/pkg`.  The yocto sdk is not working to build go programs.  I don't know why.  I see it doesn't have the src component of the stdlib but does have the pkg part for the architecture it should support, which is cross-compiling.  Thus my question, is the src for stdlib necessary to compile go programs?

Comment: No, it is not .

Answer (score 1):

### src

This directory contains source files organized as packages.

### pkg

This directory contains Go package objects compiled from src directory Go source code packages. If a package does not contain a file with `main` package declaration, then Go creates a package archive (.a) file inside `pkg` directory. Package object are used at link time to create the complete Go executable binary in the bin directory.

So once we compile a package then we can link that object in many executables. Like, 
`fmt` is the compiled library in `pkg`, so no need to compile again. We can link that object to run all the Go programs.

Comment: These directories are part of the golang package and owned by root.  Obviously a user doesn't write any applications and place anything here.

Comment: @TrentP you mean go installed `src` right ? then I updated my ans.

Answer (score 1):

The Go installation `pkg` tree contains multiple distinct things:

- In the `pkg/tool` tree there is the Go compiler itself, and other related tools.  These are binaries for certain *os-arch* combinations.  This is, of course, entirely necessary to build go software.
- There will also be one or more *os-arch* tree(s) with compiled libraries for the go stdlib.  For a go installation intended for cross-compilation, this will not be the same os-arch combination as the in `pkg/tool`.
- There are also some C header files in `pkg/include`.

In the Go installation `src` tree there are multiple distinct things:

- Under `src/cmd`, there is the source to the Go compiler and tools.  This source is not needed to build go software.
- Elsewhere in `src` is the source to the go stdlib.  This is also necessary to build software.

The libraries and executables in `pkg` were built for specific *os-arch* combo(s) from the sources in `src`.

The libraries are not need to build software as go will rebuild from the source.  The executables are necessary and the `go` build system will use them.

The source to the compiler in `src` is not necessary.
The **source to the go stdlib is necessary**, at least for all practical purposes.  `go build` will insist on looking for the source and refuse to build if it's not present, even if a suitable compiled library is available.

There was support for binary only packages from go 1.7 to go 1.12, but it was dropped.